# Ajaxify calendar

Tags: jquery, ajax, calendar

I need ajaxify "next" and "prev" links in wordpress calendar for navigation of months, without updating the page.

There is some plugins for this - but I call calendar without using widgets - get_calendar();

Answer (score 1):

Write your required javascript, then use this code to display it on the page, it ensures that the script is only included if the calendar is displayed

```
add_filter('get_calendar',  'add_calendar_scripts');
function add_calendar_scripts($content) {
    add_action( 'wp_footer', 'output_calendar_scripts', 11);
    return $content;
}

function output_calendar_scripts() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/path/to/script.js"></script>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: i can`t write that script - i wrote some script but it didn`t work.

Comment: I'm sorry but it won't work without it

Comment: @Ronin As in the [faq#questions] stated, I want to note that we **do not handle** questions, that require professional hands-on involvement, which are overly complex and specific things (known as work for me for free). If you can't do it by  yourself with the help provided, then you will need to hire a developer to code this for you.